# Binding to a specific network interface on a Linux server with multiple gateways

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, network-interface

I'm trying to run a server program on my local machine. It has 2 routes to the Internet:

- `10.0.0.1/24` on `eth0` is the gateway and subnet on the interface with the fastest connection; however, a firewall prevents me from accessing any servers bound to TCP ports.
- `10.8.0.1/24` on `eth1` is the gateway and subnet on the slower interface; however, I am in control of the gateway device and am able to successfully port forward through it and the server is visible on the Internet.

On my machine, I have these routes:

`default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 src 10.0.0.x metric 203 
default via 10.8.0.1 dev eth1 metric 800 
10.8.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.y 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.x metric 203`

Clearly, the route via `eth0` would take priority under normal circumstances; however, for my server to be port-forwarded, it needs to use the default gateway on the `eth1` interface *without* redirecting all of the other traffic through the same interface.

What I've tried so far is to bind the server to the address `10.8.0.y` which means it would only accept connections whose destination is that IP address. However, it has not worked for routing traffic in the opposite direction. I have verified using `tcpdump -i eth1 -p 25561` that inbound connections are being received, but when monitoring both `eth0` and `eth1` I do not see a an outbound reply. The connection will then time out on the remote client upon receiving no reply.

Has anyone else tried to do something similar and can provide some insight on how I need to set it up?

Comment: Usually you need the use of `ip route table` combined with `ip rule` to link a source IP to a matching destination route. Take a look at http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html . Consider your local machine is the linux router connected to provider 1 and provider 2 for the sake of following the explanations there. You can then even use iptables to select the right provider (for example by selecting the right source ip).

Comment: Also with the use of routing tables (as in lartc.org's page) I don't think it's needed at all, but else, perhaps you can make it work just by  disabling rp_filter (reverse path filtering). Look at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt (rp_filter entry). Disable it both for `all` and `eth1`.